# Android: Scoreloop vs OpenFeint

Tags: android, openfeint, scoreloop

Any comparison between OpenFient and Scoreloop for Android?

Comment: could you split your question into a question and an answer that we could mark as comminty wiki? that way it better fits this sites format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before writing our latest game that is using a "Social Scoring system", I could not find a good comparison for OpenFeint and Scoreloop for Android.

We started off with the OpenFeint implementation, and moved on to use Scoreloop, which was the one to launch (see: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scoompa.marbles)

Here are the reasons that made us switch, in case anyone else wants to choose between the two:

1. OF documentation looks like it was ported from iOS, and very badly so. For example, the docs gives an example of initializing OF in your Application class. This will cause their "Join / Don't like fun" full screen dialog appear out of the blue, when users are busy using other applications, as android will kill and re-create your application in the background as memory availability change.
2. ScoreLoop automatically creates a "userId" for the user, without them having to register / login. This allowed us to post user's highscores and display their highscores without having to bother the user for logging in.
3. Scoreloop have an "offline" mode, which makes it much more robust, efficient, accurate and easy to use.
4. In flaky network situations, OF login process took a very long time, and affected the game performance. (see #3 above).
5. OF does not allow you to fetch a score rank. If you want to get your user's rank, you have to fetch the complete leaderboard, cycle through it until you find your user's entry. This "solution" pretty much makes this option not-available.
6. Scoreloop provided us with grate support. I've opened several tickets, they all got answered promptly and professionally. These guys rock.

I wrote this code a while back, so there might have been other reasons which I forget.

**Edit**:

In April 2011, Japanese company GREE, Inc. bought OpenFeint for US$104 million. According to the [FAQ posted here](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/OpenFeint-GREE-FAQ/) following the acquisition "The OpenFeint SDK will remain and still be free to use. The entire OpenFeint team is staying and we’re planning on doubling our headcount over the next few months so that we can continue to bring you the best in social, engagement, and discovery features for your games."

Answer (score 3):

GREE is shutting down the OpenFeint servers on December 14th 2012. They provide an api migration guide which, they admit, is out of date and is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

OpenFeint is deperacted and is now GREE.
The OpenFeint SDK is no longer supported, so the best choice will be to use ScoreLoop or something else.